# Self-hosted open source alternative for PackageCloud.io

Tags: open-source, web-apps, self-hosted, package-manager

PackageCloud.io is a web service for hosting repositories for Debian/Ubuntu/Suse/… easily.

Is there an open source alternative to their software which offers similar features and can be self-hosted?

I need support for deb and rpm  package as well as for different versions of a distribution.

Comment: http://pulpproject.org/ is the best option out there, not nearly as user friendly though.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.